# Issue with constructor initialization in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, constructor, monorepo, pinata

Pinata SDK: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pinata/sdk

I trying to use the Pinata SDK in one of the packages of a Nx Typescript monorepo project. I installed the SDK with: `yarn add @pinata/sdk -W`. Now using it in a package A file: `packages/A/src/lib/encryption.ts` where the monorepo structure is like:

```
packages
  - A
  - B
```

Now initializing the SDK as:

```
import pinataSDK from '@pinata/sdk';
const pinata = new pinataSDK.default('yourPinataApiKey', 'yourPinataSecretApiKey');
// const pinata = new pinataSDK({ pinataApiKey: 'yourPinataApiKey', pinataSecretApiKey: 'yourPinataSecretApiKey' }); // Tried this way too which doesn't work either
```

I get the following error:

```
const pinata = new sdk_1.default('yourPinataApiKey', 'yourPinataSecretApiKey');
                   ^
TypeError: sdk_1.default is not a constructor
```

I tried a different way of importing too:

```
import * as pinataSDK from '@pinata/sdk';
```

This also gave a similar error:

```
const pinata = new pinataSDK.default('yourPinataApiKey', 'yourPinataSecretApiKey');
                   ^
TypeError: pinataSDK.default is not a constructor
```

How can properly initialize the SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing like this?

```
// Use the api keys by providing the strings directly 
const pinataSDK = require('@pinata/sdk');
const pinata = new pinataSDK('yourPinataApiKey', 'yourPinataSecretApiKey');
```

Without the **.default**. You can check on the official [docs](https://docs.pinata.cloud/docs/pinata-sdk)